# Prolog: how to write a helper that converts a result into a list?

Tags: list, prolog, helper

Let's assume I have something like:

```
% person(ID, Name, Age)
person(_, paul, Age).
person(_, Name, 20).
...
```

...and instead of the typical binding I would like to have a helper function `get_person_list(ID, Name, Age)` that calls `person` but returns me a list:

```
?- get_person_list(_, Name, 20).
[frank, jack, jane].
```

...to get a list for e.g. all persons with age 20. How can I achieve this?

Comment: There is a problem with the way you have decided to organize your data. You have an argument for the ID, but in your example you leave those "anonymous". Instead, you can normalize your database and simply have `id_name/2` and `id_age/2`, for example (I don't know what you are trying to model though... can a person have a name and age but no ID? Or the name or age are not known? either way, normalizing the database and just leaving out rows for the details you don't know is much cleaner that leaving "holes" in the table.)

Comment: PS: and of course, you do need a "primary key", and usually the ID plays the role of the primary key. But since you have left out the ID in both rows you have in your example, I am a bit confused. The name is a very bad primary key, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `findall/3` for this. This is the perfect example of how `bagof/3` and `setof/3` are different from `findall/3`.

Your example is a bit strange, so here is another database. I removed the first argument because you don't seem to be using it, and added more rows so that there can be more different ages. Note that it makes no sense to have free variables in a table of facts like `person`, so all rows have values at both positions.

```
person(abel, 20).
person(bill, 30).
person(clive, 20).
person(diana, 10).
person(evan, 200).
person(fia, 20).

people_age(Age, Ps) :-
        bagof(P, person(P, Age), Ps).
```

With this definition of `people_age/2`, you can query, for example:

> Who are the people aged 20?

```
?- people_age(20, Ps).
Ps = [abel, clive, fia].
```

> Group people by their age.

```
?- people_age(Age, Ps).
Age = 10,
Ps = [diana] ;
Age = 20,
Ps = [abel, clive, fia] ;
Age = 30,
Ps = [bill] ;
Age = 200,
Ps = [evan].
```

> Who is at least 30 years old?

```
?- people_age(Age, Ps), Age >= 30.
Age = 30,
Ps = [bill] ;
Age = 200,
Ps = [evan].
```

The last one could be done differently, if you don't want to group by age. Here is how:

```
?- bagof(P, Age^( person(P, Age), Age >= 30 ), Ps).
Ps = [bill, evan].
```

or maybe

```
?- bagof(Age-P, Age^( person(P, Age), Age >= 30 ), Ps).
Ps = [30-bill, 200-evan].
```

... if you don't want to throw away the age completely.

But you should just read up on "collecting all solutions in Prolog" and the intended use of all three: `findall/3`, `bagof/3`, `setof/3`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you don't provide a parameter for the resulting list.

Just call:

```
findall(Id, person(Id, _, 20), L).
```

You can make a separate predicate for this query if you really need it often, of course.

```
get_person_list(Id, List) :- 
  findall(Id, person(Id, _, 20), List).
```

See also `bagof/3`, as explained in Boris's answer.

Comment: ...but with this I will only be able to search for the ID, right? I would like to be able to have a helper function that intakes `(ID, Name, Age)`, so that I am able to search for `ID` or `Name` or `Age`. Like `(_, Name, 20)` for every Name without `ID` aged 20. Or `(ID, paul, _)` for all `paul`'s, regardless of the age, together with the ID.

Comment: @ascenator Yes, but that's the part where *you* do some work. You have both a `findall` example and one possible helper predicate. See how you could add parameters to `get_person_list` and use them in the query.

Comment: How does `findall(Id, _, 20, L).` work? You didn't specify the list `person` on which `findall` should operate?!

Comment: @ascenator when you call `person(Id,Name,20)`, prolog try to unify `Id` and   `Name` with all the combinations that succeed, based on the existing *facts* you already defined. This works thanks to backtracking. For example, when you write queries in the interpreter, it may ask you if you want to search for more solutions once a first one has been found. `Findall` does the same, but automatically collect all solutions into a list (with a hidden mutable data structure). http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse49

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write: `findall(X,person(_,X,20),L).` 
This will return you a list L which  is the list you asked...

Example:

```
person(_, name1, 20).
person(_, name2, 20).
person(_, name3, 20).
person(_, name4, 20).
person(_, name5, 20).

?- findall(X,person(_,X,20),L).
L = [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5].
```

Comment: If I do `findall(X,person(_,X,20),L).` I get `L = [_G6034, _G6031, _G6028, _G6025, _G6022, _G6019, _G6016, _G6013, _G6010|...].` instead of the names aged 20. What's wrong there?

Comment: You possibly have names starting with capitals. In Prolog capitals are used for variables. In your example it returns a list with variables.... In the example posted it works fine...